# i am moving my existing project(present in was 9) to jboss eap 7.3

Tags: java, spring

Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.(Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/springframework/context/support/AbstractXmlApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext used in the signature

i have included spring 4.3.24 jars in lib and as dependency..

Comment: **i have included spring 4.3.24 jars in lib and as dependency..** Which is the cause of this issue. Remove them from the shared lib folder and only use them as dependencies.

Comment: after removing it i am getting below error :Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext from [Module "deployment.myapp.ear.myapp.war" from Service Module Loader]

Comment: Which means you haven't included the jars as dependencies in your app.

Comment: Can you give me the folder structure module.xml.. should i create it under modules/org/springframework ?

Comment: No it should be part of your dependencies of your application, it shouldbn't be a module within your server. If you do that you endup with issues when you include (part of) Spring into your application.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ExtendedProperties
 yes i am getting this error now

Comment: ARe you hunting for dependencies yourself? Those should have been part of the application (or maybe they were part of WAS). You really should be using something like maven or gradle to manage your dependencies and build your software .